Removing the cosmic horizon in the de Sitter metric
The metric for de Sitter spacetime in static coordinates is
$$ds^2 = \left(1-\frac{r^2}{\ell^2}\right)dt^2 - \frac {1}{1 - \frac{r^2}{\ell^2}}dr^2 - r^2\,d\Omega_2^2.$$
It is evident that there exists a singularity at $r = \ell$. My question is, in what way can we remove this singularity? I am studying a complex scalar field theory in this particular spacetime, and I would like to make an appropriate coordinate transformation so that the singularity disappears from the equations of motion.

The same way as we did in pure Schwarzschild: transform to Nullcoordinates and then apply T=u±r for your new time coordinate.

You can remove the singularity by the same trick that removes the singularity of Schwarzschild coordinates: substitute $t = u + f(r)$ for some $f$. Taking $f(r) = \ell \tanh^{-1} (r/\ell) - r$ gives the metric
$$ds^2 = (1 - r^2/\ell^2)\,du^2 + 2\ (r^2/\ell^2)\,du\,dr - (1 + r^2/\ell^2)\,dr^2 - r^2 dΩ^2$$
in which the radial outward speed of light is $1$ and the radial inward speed is $\dfrac{1-r^2/\ell^2}{1+r^2/\ell^2}$. Whether that's suitable for your application I don't know. It covers only half of the de Sitter spacetime (again, like the analogous metric for the Schwarzschild manifold).

Would the other half of the manifold be given in this case by taking $f(r) = \ell \tanh ^{-1}(r/\ell) + r$?
